# How to get basic coroutine health metrics?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**tl;dr: How can I get a glimpse of basic state for a coroutine dispatcher?**

Specifically:

1. How many total coroutines are active?
2. Is the dispatcher exceeding its maximum parallelism? (e.g. are there coroutines stuck waiting)

###### Context:

I'm running a game server where coroutines are used to listen on ports, handle asynchronous work, manage game state, etc. It is very easy to introduce subtle latency bugs where someone adds a new coroutine inside of a request and then the coroutine load substantially increases and request latency suffers (and in rare cases, deadlocks).

Optimal coroutine scheduling is integral to a good user experience for my service and is something I want to measure. Are there any available health metrics I can observe related to coroutines?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @Al.G. After a fair bit of research I'm pretty sure there are no existing tools to let you do this. If you're running into a similar problem it might be a good idea to make your own threadpools and use `asCoroutineDispatcher()` for finer control.